# How to write ill-formatted header lines to a csv with R data.table fwrite?

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, fread

I have the following *csv file, with has three "header" fields which are formatted differently than a csv file, `example.csv`:

```
# Filename is addresses.csv
# Location of file from https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/csv.html
# The data isn't authentic
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

Normally, I would read in the file with R data.table, skipping the initial lines.

```
library(data.table)
dt = fread('addresses.csv', skip=3)
## do something
```

After analyzing/manipulating the data, I normally write the file as the following:

```
fwrite(dt, "result.csv", col.names=FALSE)
```

The problem with this is that, I have erased the original header lines.

Is there a standard approach for reading in the original header lines, and appending them to the final result to write via `fwrite()`? I think there will be parsing errors if I append these header lines to `dt` before using `fwrite()`

EDIT:
Note I would like the header lines to be preserved, i.e.

```
# Filename is addresses.csv
# Location of file from https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/csv.html
# The data isn't authentic
```

Comment: You could always read the original header (`orig_colnames`) and change the ones in the data table before saving to file: `colnames(dt) <- orig_colnames`. Doesn't this work?

Comment: Reading in the first three lines only is tricky, i.e. `fread('addresses.csv', nrows=3)` doesn't work. It's also not clear to be if `colnames(dt) <- orig_colnames` would map the column names in a sensible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by writing the hearder lines from the original file with [`write(header_lines, filename)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/write), followed by your `fwrite` command with the option `append=T`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this will make each header line a separate column. I think I'll try to detail the question a bit better to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry! I completely misunderstood what your question was! Changed my answer @EB2127